# Displaying strings in different ways

Tags: php, html, css

I'm creating a module for news display. I'd like to know if there's a better way to display info of my article. I want to be able to display info parts in different ways, with on/off functionality. For example:

1. Title
2. Text
3. Readmore
4. Date
5. Author

or just

1. Readmore
2. Title

I'm thinking of this code, but I believe there's a better solution?

```
<div id="pos1">
<?php
if ( show = 1 ) {
echo 'Here will be title';
elseif ( show = 2 ) {
echo 'Here will be text';
elseif ( show = 3 ) {
echo 'Here will be readmore';
.....
else { $string = 'nothing here'; }
?></div>

<div id="pos2">
<?php
if ( showsecond = 1 ) {
echo 'Here will be title';
elseif ( showsecond = 2 ) {
echo 'Here will be text';
elseif ( showsecond = 3 ) {
echo 'Here will be readmore';
.....
else { $string = 'nothing here'; }
?></div>
```

Comment: is `show, showsecond` a variable ? where did they come from

Comment: `show` and `showsecond` are not valid variables, php will interpret them as the literal string `show` and `showsecond` all variables must be prefixed with "$"

Comment: they are not valid, also how many post are there ? all of them storing on separated variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$info = array(
    1 => 'This will be the title',
    2 => 'this will be the text',
    3 => 'This is the readmore',
    4 => 'Date',
    5 => 'Author'
);

echo $info[$show];
```

**Edit:**

```
$info = array(
    1 => array(
        'text' => 'This will be the title',
        'styles' => 'styling info goes here'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'text' => 'This will be the author',
        'styles' => 'styling info goes here'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'text' => 'This will be the date',
        'styles' => 'styling info goes here'
    )
);

echo $info[$show]['text'];
```

Comment: I need to add divs for styling each of them sepparatly. I can't see how this could be done here.. ?