# Are there other ways to display information?

Tags: php, string, templates

I want to display my articles info in different ways, with on/off functionality, something like this:
1.title
2.text
3.date
or
1.title
2.readmore button
3.text
etc...

The script below can do this, but it's kinda long and complicated are there are other ways to do that ? Without using array.

$firstpositioninfo is info field to display. 1 - title, 2 text etc..

```
<div id="pos1">
<?php
if ( $firstpositioninfo = 1 ) {
echo 'Here will be title';
elseif ( $firstpositioninfo = 2 ) {
echo 'Here will be text';
elseif ( $firstpositioninfo = 3 ) {
echo 'Here will be readmore';
.....
else { }
?></div>

<div id="pos2">
<?php
if ( $firstpositioninfo = 1 ) {
echo 'Here will be title';
elseif ( $firstpositioninfo = 2 ) {
echo 'Here will be text';
elseif ( $firstpositioninfo = 3 ) {
echo 'Here will be readmore';
.....
else { }
?></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying strings in different ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069720/displaying-strings-in-different-ways)

Comment: Well, I just said if there are other ways to do it without arrays. Using arrays impossible, or atleast I don't know how to store <?php ?>+html in an array.

Comment: On a side note, your script shouldn't give result as expected. You are using assigning sign instead of equality sign in each of your if case. Which means, your if will always be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, a lot of better solutions exist...

Try:

```
switch($firstpositioninfo):
case 1:
   for each post, display it properly
   break;
(...)
```

Displaying each post should be also declared as function, check [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: Not sure how to use this, it's similar to the code above or i'm missing something?

Comment: in code above, only once is checked your condition, and after that for each post we will print it for current mode. Each post should be printed the same way, right?